# Movie where unfunny Improv ideas are yelled at improv troupe

Tags: identify-this-movie

This is a relatively new movie, Hollywood release. I can't remember who's in it, but I'm pretty sure there's at least one famous actor in it. In one particular scene, this group of friends (I think 4 of them) decide to go to an improv comedy show and hurl the most unfunny ideas possible at them.  For instance, one of the improv guys says something like, "I need an event" and one of the guys yells "9/11!".  Stuff like that.

Any ideas?

Comment: Downvoter - Care to explain?

Comment: I think this is a legit question, and I remember the scene too, so I added an upvote to balance out the downvote.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a scene from **Ted 2**. I thought they just ripped it off *Family Guy*.

And there are like 100 famous actors in it, staring and cameos. Like the Tick and Worf.

[image]

Comment: And Flash Gordon.  :o)